# Breadth First Search with list of coordinates python

Tags: python, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am building a simple A.I for a "spider game" (pretty much the same concept as the snake game but the moving logic is a bit different). I am trying to implement a BFS algorithm such that the spider finds the path that leads it to the ant. The algorithm seems to work for several iterations but when I run it outside of the debugger it gets a `None` value inside the `node_list` and that makes the other methods fail (since you cannot get the next move for anything).

This is the BFS algorithm:

```
def BFS(spider_state, ant_state):
    goal = False
    count = 0
    initial_node = Node(spider_state, None, 0)
    node_list = [initial_node]
    initial_ant_state = ant_state

    while goal == False or len(node_list) == 0:
        e = node_list.pop(0)
        future_ant_state = initial_ant_state
        for i in range(0, e.depth):
            future_ant_state = get_next_ant_move(border_choice, initial_ant_state)
        for move in POSSIBLE_MOVES:
            count += 1
            next_node = Node(None, None, None)
            next_node.state = get_next_spider_move(deepcopy(e.state), move)
            next_node.parent = e
            next_node.depth = e.depth + 1
            if next_node.state == future_ant_state:
                goal = True
                break
            else:
                node_list.append(next_node)
    return node_list
```

Node:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, state, parent, depth):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.depth = depth
```

Spider and ant are represented as a simple list of `x` and `y` positions:

```
spider = [15, 35]
ant = [20, 10]
```

The `get next move` methods look like this:

```
def get_next_spider_move(spidy, move):
    if spidy:
        # check the bounds and assign the new value to spidy
        spidy = spider_bounds(spidy)
        # farthest right
        if move == 0:
            spidy[1] += 2
            spidy[0] -= 1
        # furhter up and right
        if move == 1:
            spidy[1] += 1
            spidy[0] -= 2
        # backwords
        if move == 2:
            spidy[0] += 1
        # farthest left
        if move == 3:
            spidy[1] -= 2
            spidy[0] -= 1
        # furhter up and to the left
        if move == 4:
            spidy[1] += 1
            spidy[0] -= 2
        # one left
        if move == 5:
            spidy[1] -= 1
        # one right
        if move == 6:
            spidy[1] -= 1
        # side right
        if move == 7:
            spidy[1] += 1
            spidy[0] += 1
        # side left
        if move == 8:
            spidy[1] -= 1
            spidy[0] -= 1
        else:
            # if no valid direction was given
            return spidy
    else:
        raise ValueError('spidy must contain an x and y position. %s',  spidy, ' was found')
```

The resulting error when run:

```
    File "spider_game_bfs.py", line 141, in <module>
    path = BFS(spider, ant)
  File "spider_game_bfs.py", line 130, in BFS
    next_node.state = get_next_spider_move(deepcopy(e.state), move)
  File "spider_game_bfs.py", line 100, in get_next_spider_move
    raise ValueError('spidy must contain an x and y position. %s',  spidy, ' was found')
ValueError: ('spidy must contain an x and y position. %s', None, ' was found')
```

Comment: your `get_next_move` function will be faster if the subsequent `if` statements are changed to `elif`, since the conditions are mutually exclusive

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.   
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Even after I fixed your indentation and supplied a missing main program, the code fails on an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logic error at the bottom of your move function.  The last complete statement is

```
    if move == 8:
        spidy[1] -= 1
        spidy[0] -= 1
    else:
        # if no valid direction was given
        return spidy
```

Your comment is incorrect: the `else` clause is executed by any move *other* than 8.  If the move *is* 8, then you return `None`, as you've skipped the statement that returns `spidy`.

As the first comment mentioned, you will do better with `if ... elif ... else` as your logic structure.  Even better than that, follow the many on-line examples for moving an item: make a list or dict of the moves, something like this:

```
move_dir = [
    (-1, +2),  # move 0
    (-2, +1),  # move 1
    (+1,  0),  # move 2
    ...        # fill in the rest
]

if move in range(len(move_dir)):
    spidy[0] += move_dir[move[0]]
    spidy[1] += move_dir[move[1]]
    return spidy
else:
    raise ValueError ...
```